# How to import blade-ui-kit into Vue.js 3 component

Tags: laravel, uikit, vuejs3

In the Blade template it works normally, but on the `App.vue` it doesn't… Does anyone know how I can import?

`App.vue`:

```
<template>

  <div v-if="showText" class="container">
    <p>{{ title }} - {{ age }}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" v-on:click="age++">Increase age</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" v-on:click="age--">Increase age</button>

    <button class="changeTitle btn btn-sm btn-warning" @click="changeTitle">Change Title</button><br>
    <div class="contButton">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info show" @click="showText = !showText">show</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for=" book in books ">
          <h3>{{ book.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ book.author }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="container">
    {{ title }}
    <div class="contButton">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info show" @click="showText = !showText">show</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'The Final Empire',
      age: 45,
      showText: false,
      books: [
        { title: 'name of the wind', author: 'Patrick Rothfuss', isFav: false },
        { title: 'the way of king', author: 'Brandon Sanderson', isFav: false },
        { title: 'the final empire', author: 'Patrick Rothfuss', isFav: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeTitle(){
      this.title = 'The new title!'
    },
  }
}
```

`app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './vue/App.vue'

createApp(App).mount("#app")
```

I've already read all documentation of the `blade-ui-kit`, but it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use blade in .vue files, am I right? If yes, then you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163567/how-can-i-use-blade-in-vue-files) (but also, please, take into account that Vue 2 is used there). If this isn't what you want, feel free to say so.